# Showing a HTML when document starts loading and dismiss and html when document fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show an popup when an HTML start loading and dismiss that popup when document loaded fully. Is there any event in JQuery to catch both events?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a jQuery for that. In document's **head** section if you insert a script like this:

```
<script>
  showPopup();
</script>
```

.. it will be executed before HTML has loaded. And if you execute script like this:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    hidePopup();
  }
</script>
```

.. it will be executed after the page has loaded